# Javascript for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs, blogger

I am trying to copy the dropdown menu (the one with red background) of this site: http://bloggerstore-javatemplates.blogspot.com/ to my blog. I *think* I have copied the css codes but I am not sure how to get the javascript codes. Could you please see what I can do to make the dropdown to my website @ http://allfacebookgames.blogspot.com/2011/11/mafia-wars-2.html. Also, I am getting a black dot beside the menu and I am not sure why is it there. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown list they are using is SuperFish (a pluging for jquery), you can get it 
[here](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

add property  **list-style: none;**

to your css element :  **.nav li**

and the dots wont be displayed

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on the dropdown menu?